# Give a color for ID even and odd

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have news from my DB. I would like to know how to give a color for ID even and odd? A grey for an even and a white for an odd?

```
$req = $bdd->query('SELECT id, titre, contenu, DATE_FORMAT(date_creation, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%i\') AS date_creation_fr FROM billets ORDER BY date_creation DESC LIMIT '.$depart.', '.$articlesPage);
```

Comment: you can  do this when render  the result  adding for example different class  to the divs that contain you rows of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fetching result, in foreach, you can check if id is dividable by `2`.
If it's dividable, then its even, otherwise its odd.

```
if(($news->id % 2) === 1){
  // It's odd
}else{
  // It's even
}
```

Comment: so it's something like that?
`$req = $bdd->query('SELECT id, titre, contenu, DATE_FORMAT(date_creation, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%i\') AS date_creation_fr FROM billets ORDER BY date_creation DESC LIMIT '.$depart.', '.$articlesPage);
 
    while ($donnees = $req->fetch())
    {
  if(($news->id % 2) === 1){
    .style1{
background-color : #F2F1EB;
}
  }
  else{
    .style1{
background-color : #FFFFFF;
}
  }`

Comment: Isn't it better to have two different div with your desired background color and, call them in html with this php if-else condition?

Comment: Yes you're right. But I have an error because $id is not defined. I don't understand how to do in this case
`$req = $bdd->query('SELECT id, titre, contenu, DATE_FORMAT(date_creation, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%i\') AS date_creation_fr FROM billets ORDER BY date_creation DESC LIMIT '.$depart.', '.$articlesPage);
 
    while ($donnees = $req->fetch())
    {
  if(($req->id % 2) === 1){
?>
<div id="coulalter1"></div> 
<?php
}else{?>
  <div id="coulalter2"></div> 

  <?php
}
    ?>`

Comment: You have to access `$donnees` to get id, not `$req` in `if` statement.

Comment: I did :  `while ($donnees = $req->fetch())
    {
  $id=$_POST['id'];
  if(($donnees->$id%2) === 1){
?>
<div id="coulalter1"></div>` 
But I have an undefined id  and  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: why have you used `$` sign in `$donnees->$id` ? use `$donnees->id` instead.
And, there is no reason to assign `$_POST['id']` to `$id`, why do you need that?

Comment: Yes but in this case I have an error Trying to get property of non-object in this line :  if(($donnees->id % 2) === 1){

Comment: try `fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch()`
and,you should `var_dump($donnees);` in while loop to check what are you getting in`$donnees` variable.

Comment: I did : while ($donnees = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
and I use var_dump and all is good I think but get property of non object... My var dump shows me :
C:\wamp64\www\test\index.php:47:
array (size=4)
  'id' => string '7' (length=1)
  'titre' => string 'arti journalistique' (length=19)
  'contenu' => string 'vpsdnvspvns' (length=11)
  'date_creation_fr' => string '09/02/2017 à 10h00' (length=19)

Comment: Oh, my bad, I totally forgot you were fetching result as `array`, to access id from array, you have to use `[]`, eg. `$donnees['id']`

Comment: Like it ? `while ($donnees = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
  var_dump($donnees);
  
  if(($donnees['id'] % 2) === 1){
?>`
I don't have any error but there is no color ^^

Comment: My all code is :

    `while ($donnees = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {  
  if(($donnees['id'] % 2) === 1){
?>
<div id="coulalter1"></div> 
<?php
}else{?>
  <div id="coulalter2"></div> 

  <?php
}
    ?>
     
    <div class="news">
        <div class="beaute">
       <a href="commentaires.php?billet=<?php echo $donnees['id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $donnees['date_creation_fr']; ?>
            <em> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($donnees['titre']); ?>
            </em></a>
        </div>
     </div>`

Comment: code looks fine to me, check browser source code to find out which div has been printed.

Comment: I have <div id="coulalter1"></div>
     
    <div class="news">
        <div class="beaute">
       <a href="commentaires.php?billet=7">
            09/02/2017 à 10h00            <em> arti journalistique            </em></a></div>
        </div>
     </div>
I think the div coulalter 1 can't be active because I close it after I opened it. Maybe put </div> later?

Comment: or because I close the "if" before my list of id?

Comment: yeah, you have to close div later.

Comment: So I must to close the if after the </div> ? Right?
Like it </div>} ? Because I don't understand where to close it.. If I do it after my list, I lose some id..

Comment: `while ($donnees = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { if(($donnees['id'] % 2) === 1){ ?> <div id="coulalter1"> <?php }else{?> <div id="coulalter2"> <?php } ?> <div class="news"> <div class="beaute"> <a href="commentaires.php?billet=<?php echo $donnees['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $donnees['date_creation_fr']; ?> <em> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($donnees['titre']); ?> </em></a> </div> </div></div>`

Comment: I covered all the id but between every id, there is a space empty.. Look at my CSS: 

`#coulalter1{
 background-color:#999;
 width:300px;
 height:20px;
}
#coulalter2{
 background-color:#FFF;
 width:300px;
 height:20px;
}



.beaute
{
    text-align:center;
}

#coulalter1 :hover{
background:#CCC;
}
#coulalter2 :hover{
background:#CCC;
}

.news
{
    width:300px;
 height:10px;
}


a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}`

Comment: I am not a front-end developer, I can't help you with css. Sorry !

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using php:

```
if(($news->id % 2) === 1){
  // It's odd
}
else{
  // It's even
}
```

Or if you are using html table than it can also achieve by using css:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: so it's something like that?
`$req = $bdd->query('SELECT id, titre, contenu, DATE_FORMAT(date_creation, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%i\') AS date_creation_fr FROM billets ORDER BY date_creation DESC LIMIT '.$depart.', '.$articlesPage);
 
    while ($donnees = $req->fetch())
    {
  if(($news->id % 2) === 1){
    .style1{
background-color : #F2F1EB;
}
  }
  else{
    .style1{
background-color : #FFFFFF;
}
  }`